# Postgres: complex foreign key constraints

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, schema

I have this schema

```
CREATE TABLE public.item (
    itemid integer NOT NULL,
    itemcode character(100) NOT NULL,
    itemname character(100) NOT NULL,
    constraint PK_ITEM primary key (ItemID)
);
create unique index ak_itemcode on Item(ItemCode);

CREATE TABLE public.store (
    storeid character(20) NOT NULL,
    storename character(80) NOT NULL,
    constraint PK_STORE primary key (StoreID)
);

CREATE TABLE public.storeitem (
    storeitemid integer NOT NULL,
    itemid integer NOT NULL,
    storeid character(20) NOT NULL,
    constraint PK_STOREITEM primary key (ItemID, StoreID),
    foreign key (StoreID) references Store(StoreID),
    foreign key (ItemID) references Item(ItemID)
);

create unique index ak_storeitemid on StoreItem (StoreItemID);
```

And here is the data on those tables

```
insert into Item (ItemID, ItemCode,ItemName)
 Values (1,'abc','abc');
insert into Item (ItemID, ItemCode,ItemName)
 Values (2,'def','def');
insert into Item (ItemID, ItemCode,ItemName)
 Values (3,'ghi','ghi');
insert into Item (ItemID, ItemCode,ItemName)
 Values (4,'lmno','lmno');
insert into Item (ItemID, ItemCode,ItemName)
 Values (5,'xyz','xyz');

insert into Store (StoreID, StoreName)
 Values ('B1','B1');

insert into StoreItem (StoreItemID, StoreID, ItemID)
 Values (1,'B1',1);
insert into StoreItem (StoreItemID, StoreID, ItemID)
 Values (2,'B1',2);
insert into StoreItem (StoreItemID, StoreID, ItemID)
 Values (3,'B1',3);
```

Now I created this new table

```
CREATE TABLE public.szdata (
    storeid character(20) NOT NULL,
    itemcode character(100) NOT NULL,
    textdata character(20) NOT NULL,
    constraint PK_SZDATA primary key (ItemCode, StoreID)
);
```

I want to have the foreign key constraints set so that it will fail when you try to insert record which is not in StoreItem. For example this must fail

```
insert into SZData (StoreID, ItemCode, TextData)
 Values ('B1', 'xyz', 'text123');
```

and this must pass

```
insert into SZData (StoreID, ItemCode, TextData)
 Values ('B1', 'abc', 'text123');
```

How do I achieve this without complex triggers but using table constraints?
I prefer solution without triggers. SZData table is just for accepting input from external world and it is for single purpose.
Also database import export must not be impacted

Comment: You seem to want a compound FK: one with multiple columns, whose values must all be there in the same row in the referenced table as the referencing table. Research including every section FKs are mentioned on in the DBMS manual. You know about FKs so why haven't you? (Rhetorical.) PS Your DBMS may have to define the columns in the same order in the CREATE, PK/UNIQUE & REFERENCES. Read everything in the manual for you DBMS about those things & constraints & indexes. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: @philipxy, I did my research and all points to triggers which I dont want to enable it just for this one table. There are 10s of tables and dont have triggers. I know the frustration when we dont know the answers but I am sure there are brilliant minds out there who might come up with a solution. That the whole purpose of posting it on stackflow. No point trying to shut that off.

Comment: 1) Get out of the habit of `itemcode` an then `key (ItemCode, ...)` that is depending on unquoted identifiers being down cased. At some point you will run into a client/framework/etc that automatically double quotes all identifiers and this will blow up. 2) In `cidata` this `itemcode` should be `itemid`. 3) Once you do 2) then create a FK from `cidata` to `storeitem` on `storeid, itemid` --> `storeid, itemid`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, unfortunately cidata schema has to be like this since this table accepts input from external world. ID will makes no sense to the outside person therefore it has to be code or name.  also this is single purpose table. In future this will be discarded. Same time other table schema cannot change. Those tables are part 10s or could be 100s of tables/views in the database for a long time.

Comment: Then you are out of luck and will have use triggers. If you have a bad design then you are stuck with using work arounds.

Comment: I posted internally within company and got my answer. Thats below. It is good to know there are some brilliant minds internally. I do not have good opinion of people who criticise question when they don’t know the answer. I am not quite sure why this sort of comment is getting deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out having a function to execute on constraint will solve this issue.
The function **is_storeitem** does the validation. I believe this feature can be used for even complex validations

```
create or replace function is_storeitem(pItemcode nchar(40), pStoreId nchar(20)) returns boolean as $$
select exists (
    select 1
    from public.storeitem si, public.item i, public.store s
    where si.itemid = i.itemid and i.itemcode = pItemcode and s.Storeid = pStoreId and s.storeid = si.storeid
);
$$ language sql;


create table SZData
(
    StoreID             NCHAR(20)              not null,
    ItemCode            NCHAR(100)             not null,
    TextData            NCHAR(20)              not null,
    constraint PK_SIDATA primary key (ItemCode, StoreID),
    foreign key (StoreID) references Store(StoreID),
    foreign key (ItemCode) references Item(ItemCode),
    CONSTRAINT ck_szdata_itemcode CHECK (is_storeitem(Itemcode,StoreID))
);
```

This perfectly works with postgres 9.6 or greater.